# Preserve UTF-8 for arraylist while adding String in java

Tags: java, utf-8

I am trying to add a few Greek words to an `ArrayList` to be later on compared with the Greek words that are input to the system.  This approach is not working as it does not find the match. How do I do this correctly while preserving UTF-8 encoding?

```
try {
    el_GR_words = new ArrayList<String>();
    el_GR_words.add("μουν".getBytes("UTF-8").toString()); //example  only, I dont    know what this word means, so pardon me if it is a bad word lol
}
catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
    uee.printStackTrace();
}
ArrayList words = new ArrayList();
Iterator<String> it = el_GR_words.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String thisWord = it.next();
    if (thisWord.equalsIgnoreCase(aWord) ||    aWord.toLowerCase().contains(thisWord.toLowerCase())) { 
        words.add(thisWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile - you're trying to add a byte array to a `List<String>`. Please post a short but complete program that actually demonstrates the problem...

Comment: Interestingly, no compile errors.  But I performed a toString before adding it to the ArrayList (edited code above).  Please suggest what may be causing the equalsIgnoreCase check or the contains check to fail.  Is there a better way to ensure UTF-8 encoding is preserved to perform such a check?  Thanks again.

Comment: "Interestingly, no compile errors. But I performed a toString before adding it to the ArrayList (edited code above)." Well yes, when I say that code won't compile, I mean the code I can see, not the code I can't see :) I suggest you look at the contents of `el_GR_words`. It won't be what you expect it to be. It's not really clear why you're converting to bytes in the first place though...

Comment: I was trying various options, one of them being byteArray because I noticed that it can preserve encoding(signature atleast suggests so).   I guess, I should have asked the question without pasting my test code, sorry it was confusing.  Key question is - how do I add greek words to an arraylist in java, preseve its encoding, such that it can be later on tested for equality, comparison etc.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: There's no encoding to preserve. The string is a sequence of UTF-16 code units. That's all.

Comment: The only time you need to care about what format Strings are in is if you're reading them from another source or need to output them in a specific format.  This is why `InputStreamReader` and `PrintStream` have constructors for specifying character sets.  Sadly, `FileReader` does not and thus you should prefer `InputStreamReader` over it.

Answer (score 2):

`getByte("UTF-8").toString()` doesn't do what you think or hope it does. It converts the String into an array of bytes, and then use the standard toString() method, that basically dumps the memory address of the object. You can try it easily:

```
    System.out.println("μουν".getBytes("UTF-8").toString());
    System.out.println("μουν".getBytes("UTF-8").toString());
```

Gives, for example:

```
[B@556d8a64
[B@a98d70d
```

Just put `"μουν"` in your list, you'll be fine, the equals will work.